# How to find fontAwsome icon's name

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font-awesome icons in a react native app, therefore I installed it and imported it using ***react-native-vector-icons*** :

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
.....
<Icon name="map-pin" />
```

however I don't know where to find the name of the icons, I browsed in the font awesome web site, found some icons, but when I tried to use them, it doesn't work
 for example in their website  this [icon's](https://fontawesome.com/icons/abacus?style=solid) name is  *abacus*, however, when I use it in my app, I get a warning and the icon doesn't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you can get the names from the official [FontAwesome Webiste](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery), but you need to be careful. There are regular icons and pro icons. The pro icons are marked with a small blue banner on the right top. By default, only the free/regular icons are available in the `react-native-vector-icons` package.

**Regular Icon:**

[image: regular icon]

**Pro Icon**

[image: pro icon]

As you can see, the abacus icon is a pro icon and therefore not available in the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the icon names from here https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/

Comment: it doesn't work, I tried the : more-horizontal, but I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @aName the icon `more-horizontal` is not included in FontAwesome, it is included in Feather. If you want to use it, import it with `import IconFeather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ to find the icon names. It has all the icons in the `react-native-vector-icons` library.